# I'm starting to build a grid using HTML5 and JS, but this doesn't work?

Tags: html5-canvas

Apparently this doesn't work, and since I'm new to HTML5 I'm unsure as to why. I should get some vertical lines on the canvas. The idea is to build a grid on the canvas screen to work from, but this doesn't seem to be creating the lines for some reason.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test App</title>


<style>
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;

}
canvas {
    border:1px solid #000000;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>
<canvas id="gc" width="800" height="600"></canvas>

<script>
    function buildGrid() {
        alert("Start!");
        var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gc");
        var ctx = gameCanvas.getContext("2d");

        for (x=5; x<gameCanvas.width; x+=5) {
            console.log(x);
            ctx.moveTo(x, 10);
            ctx.lineTo(x, gameCanvas.length);
        }




        ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
        ctx.stroke();


    }
    window.onload = buildGrid();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just a typo. Voting to close. Please delete your post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
ctx.lineTo(x, gameCanvas.length);
```

Try

```
ctx.lineTo(x, gameCanvas.height);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9as7mwb6/6/

Comment: You meant to say `ctx.lineTo(x, gameCanvas.height)` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There’s no `gameCanvas.length`. It should be `gameCanvas.height`.

However, I think you should add `0.5` to each x value in order to make the edges sharp instead of blurry:

```js
for (var x = 5; x < gameCanvas.width; x += 5) {
    console.log(x);
    ctx.moveTo(x + 0.5, 10);
    ctx.lineTo(x + 0.5, gameCanvas.height);
}
```

Comment: OMG you are totally right I can't believe I did that. Thanks you!

Comment: Or pre-translate the context using `ctx.translate(0.5, 0.5);` once. This would be faster and less confusing.